# How to compare three groups to one control group without assuming equal variances?

Tags: anova, t-test, heteroscedasticity, equivalence

I need to determine if one dependent variable (tensile strength) for each of three new groups is equivalent to that from my original ("control") group. I am not concerned with how the three new groups compare to one another. I have N=10 for each group, including the control. I cannot assume equal variances.

**Which statistical analysis tool should I use?**

- Some sort of equivalency test which doesn't require limits
- 3 T-Tests
- ANOVA with Games-Howell Simultaneous Tests
- Some other test

---

Originally, I wanted to run an equivalency test, but I do not have proper specs available to create limits. So, I don't think I can run an equivalency test. Unless there is a way to run an equivalency test (H0: each new group is within given limits of the original) without limits?

If there is not another way, instead I will have to run a test which determines whether each new group differs from the original. Based on other questions in this forum, I have come to my own conclusion that I should run three separate T-Tests (control vs each new group); however, another option that has been thrown around is an ANOVA with a Games-Howell Simultaneous Test.

It may be that I just have to do a combination of tests. At this point, I am leaning toward 3 T-Tests and an Equivalency Test with limits I make up with some sort of scientific reasoning.

Comment: What does "IV" stand for?  *Dependent* variable??

Comment: IV: Independent Variable

Comment: Then this question does not seem to make sense.  What is the dependent variable that you are comparing across groups?

Comment: @whuber Ahh! My mistake - tensile strength IS the dependent variable. I will correct this in the original post.

Comment: Thank you. As far as I can tell you are not using "equivalency test" in the conventional sense, so I have removed the [tag:equivalence] tag. Note that performing three separate t-tests is problematic for two reasons: you need to compensate for multiple comparisons and the test results are (pretty strongly) dependent because they all use the same control data. Since the Games-Howell test is designed specifically for the situation you describe, why are you averse to its use?

Comment: I am not averse to its use. I just was curious of which option would be best. I have not used Games-Howell before today, so I wasn't exactly sure if I was applying it properly.

Comment: I see.  I think a small change in formatting might clarify the situation.  I also reorganized some of your material to appeal more to readers: it gets your question out in the open early and then gives your analysis. (I also took the liberty to correct the statement of the null hypothesis of equivalency tests, and consequently re-inserted the [tag:equivalence] tag.) Feel free to fix up what I did if it does not correctly reflect your intentions. It would help if you could clarify whether you really are considering equivalency tests, since they differ in purpose from the other tests.

Comment: I think what you are leaning toward is correct. You can't test equivalence without a threshold value, and it is worth having a serious conversation about what it should be. It occurs to me though that you need to test equivalence only for the treatment that differs the most from the control (AFTER dividing by standard error). With that treatment, do two one-sided t tests per the Schuirmann approach. If you conclude equivalence there, then the others will be equivalent as well.